# How can I sort an array by a key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with a bunch of keys.  I want to sort one of the keys by their values.

```
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [id] => 1 
                            [question] => Action 
                            [specific_to_movie_id] => 1
                            [total_yes] => 4 ) 
   [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [id] => 2 
                            [question] => Created by DC Comics 
                            [specific_to_movie_id] => 1 
                            [total_yes] => 1 ) 
   [2] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [id] => 3 
                            [question] => Christian Bale 
                            [specific_to_movie_id] => 1 
                            [total_yes] => 1 ) 
   )
```

The array looks like that above, and I want to sort by "Total_yes"

How can I go about doing this in PHP?

Comment: Format your output better and perhaps someone will help.

Comment: People helped anyway, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a little more complex than a standard array sort, you'll need to use `usort`:

```
function compare_items( $a, $b ) {
    return $a->total_yes < $b->total_yes;
}


$arrayToSort = array ( 
    (object) array( 
        'id' => 1, 
        'question' => 'Action', 
        'specific_to_movie_id' => 1,
        'total_yes' => 4
    ), 
    (object) array( 
        'id' => 2,
        'question' => 'Created by DC Comics',
        'specific_to_movie_id' => 1,
        'total_yes' => 1
    ),
    (object) array( 
        'id' => 3,
        'question' => 'Christian Bale',
        'specific_to_movie_id' => 1,
        'total_yes' => 1
    ) 
);


usort($arrayToSort, "compare_items");
```

If you want to reverse the sort order, just change `return $a->total_yes < $b->total_yes` to use > (greater than) instead of < (less than)

Comment: I'm not having much luck, I implemented the function and then called usort :/

Answer (score 2):

you could use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), like:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return $a < $b;
}

usort($your_array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have object, therefore you need use [usort()][http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php]

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    if ($a->total_yes == $b->total_yes)
        return 0;
    return ($a->total_yes > $b->total_yes) ? -1 : 1;});
print_r($array);
```

Comment: This worked, except it's in the opposite order than that in which I need.  Any suggestions? Thank you !

Comment: @DanielFein sorry, I'm edited my answer, now all right

Answer (score 0):

You can use Usort() that use a specific compere function:

**Definition and Usage**

> The usort() function sorts an array using a user-defined comparison
>   function.

**Syntax**

> usort(array,myfunction);

**array** -Required. Specifies the array to sort

**myfunction-Optional**. A string that define a callable comparison function. The comparison function must return an integer <, =, or > than 0 if the first argument is <, =, or > than the second argument

```
<?php

    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a->total_yes == $b->total_yes) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a->total_yes < $b->total_yes) ? -1 : 1;
    }



    usort($array, "cmp");

    ?>
```